# MySQL Left Join / explain why original order of first table not been kept?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Environment MySQL Version: 8.0.16.

Please use below code to create table and insert values:

```
create table TEST(
col1 varchar(255),
col2 varchar(255)
);

insert into TEST values
('fff','peach'),
('aaa','peach'),
('aff','apple'),
('xxx','banana'),
('ggg','peach'),
('eee','banana')
;


create table TEST_XX
(
col1 varchar(255),
col2 varchar(255),
groupID varchar(255),
type varchar(255)
);

insert into TEST_XX values
('aff','apple','4','apple'),
('xxx','banana','5','banana'),
('eee','banana','5','banana'),
('fff','peach','6','peach'),
('aaa','peach','6','peach'),
('ggg','peach','6','peach'),
('a','orange','7','orange');
```

and run such query:

```
select *
from TEST as a left join TEST_XX as B
on a.`col1`=B.`col1` and a.`col2`=B.`col2`;
```

I expected to see:

[image: expected result]

However, the actual result is:

[image: actual result]

As you can see, I expected the result to reserve the order how records are stored in table TEST. Yet this is not true from what was returned. Can anyone explain why? Anything wrong with MySQL query engine?

Comment: Simple answer: Tables represent relations, which are (multi) sets, which have no order. Unless an `ORDER BY` expression is used in a query, the DBMS is free to return the result in any order.

Comment: @sticky bit Thanks! so generally speaking, we should not try to assume any order without using ORDER BY, and this is generally true to all modern DBMS, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it.